# ¿Cómo escribo una hora que sea válida para las formulas en un excel, PhpSpreadsheet?

Tags: php, laravel, phpexcel, phpspreadsheet

queria saber si a alguien le pasa o le paso lo mismo que a mi.

Estoy trabajando en Laravel y tengo que tirar reportes en Excel con ciertos valores.

Bueno el tema es que tengo una planilla excel vacía pero con algunas fórmulas al final de la misma, cargo la planilla con las horas que necesito que se sumen al final, pero las horas no se suman.

Cuando abro el Excel generado tengo que seleccionar cada celda y apretar enter para que el Excel la sume, ya probe dandole formato y tipo de dato a las celdas de varias formas. ¿A alguien le paso y pudo solucionarlo?

```
$excelDateValue = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date::PHPToExcel('0'.$data[$i][0][2].':00' );  

$sheet->getStyle('H'.strval($j+2)) 
    ->getNumberFormat() 
    ->setFormatCode(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_DATETIME); 

$sheet->setCellValue('H'.strval($j+2), $excelDateValue);
```

Esto es un ejemplo de lo que intente para que el excel salga con los valores de las horas ya sumados y nada.

Es como si se cargara en formato string hasta que abro el excel selecciono cada celda y apreto 'Enter' recien ahi suma esa hora, pero no puedo pedirle  a los usuarios que abran los informes y seleccionen cada celda y apreten enter en cada una hasta que se sumen todas las horas.

Si alguien puede ayudarme estaria agradecido.